# Why my custom constructor is not called when an object is passed as a parameter?

Tags: c++, function, class, constructor, copy

I have the following code:

```
struct Entity {
    Entity() {
        std::cout << "[Entity] constructed\n";
    }

    ~Entity() {
        std::cout << "[Entity] destructed\n";
    }

    void Operation(void) {
        std::cout << "[Entity] operation\n";
    }
};

void funcCpy(Entity ent) {
    ent.Operation();
}

int main() {
    Entity e1;

    funcCpy(e1);
}
```

This is the output:

```
[Entity] constructed
[Entity] operation
[Entity] destructed
[Entity] destructed
```

I expected my function to use the custom constructor, so the output would look like this:

```
[Entity] constructed
[Entity] operation
[Entity] constructed
[Entity] destructed
[Entity] destructed
```

Why does this happens? How could I use my custom constructor instead?

Thanks :)

Comment: `funcCpy(e1);`  will call the copy constructor which you have not instrumented  / implemented.  Note in your output there is only 1 constructor call and 2 destructor calls.

Comment: So simple I did not see it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor

object as params will call copy constructor of class